# Azure ML Tutorial - Failed to load entrypoint automl

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm doing following tutorial. I failed to run "Create a control script".

What could be wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-hello-world

```
azureuser@kensmlcompute:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/my.name/get-started$ python run-hello.py 
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint automl = 
azureml.train.automl.run:AutoMLRun._from_run_dto with exception (pyarrow 4.0.0 
(/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages), 
Requirement.parse('pyarrow<4.0.0,>=0.17.0'), {'azureml-dataset-runtime'}).
https://ml.azure.com/runs/day1-experiment-hello_1623766747_073126f5? 
wsid=/subscriptions/1679753a-501e-4e46-9bff- 
6120ed5694cf/resourcegroups/kensazuremlrg/workspaces/kensazuremlws&tid=94fe1041-ba47-4f49- 
866b- 
06c297c116cc
azureuser@kensmlcompute:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/my.name/get-started$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error indicates that your environment is using pyarrow package which is of version 4.0.0 whereas azureml-dataset-runtime requires the package to be >=0.17.0 but <4.0.0

It would be easier for you to uninstall the package and install a specific version. The list of releases of pyarrow are available here.

Since you are using a notebook create new cells and run these commands.

```
 !pip uninstall pyarrow
 !pip install -y pyarrow==3.0.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry you're having an issue! But for questions on documentations, it's best to create an issue on the GitHub repo associated with this docs site.

[image]